# why I get empty when I use b.iloc[10:20] = b.iloc[20:30]?

Tags: pandas

I want to replace the line from 10th to 20th with the line from 20th to 30th.

But I got empty lines from 10th to 20th.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('test.csv',nrows=200, header = None)
a.iloc[10:20] = a.iloc[20:30]
a.to_csv('1.csv',index=False,header=None)
```

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is different index values, solution is assign numpy array:

```
a.iloc[10:20] = a.iloc[20:30].values
```

Or create same index in both:

```
a.iloc[10:20] = a.iloc[20:30].set_index(a.index[10:20])
```